# Angular reactive form validator is showing error message initially?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have one reactive form validator sample. it shows validation error message initially before we enter value.

expected behavior is, after enter value it has to show error message

[sample link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azrgy8?file=default.component.ts)

Comment: [`Why check dirty and touched?`](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#why-check-dirty-and-touched)

Comment: No need to use **bold** for your whole question

Comment: okay. @JamesZ  thanks for your update

Comment: Thanks @Vikas. i got your response

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to check touched for your error message like this

```
 <div *ngIf="check.errors.required && check.touched" class="e-error">
                This field is required.
 </div>
```

You are checking required so simply when you load the form then your field is obviously empty so it will throw the error.

You will get more information and example here : [Built In Validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#why-check-dirty-and-touched)  and  [Reactive Form Validattions](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/10/angular-6-reactive-forms-validation-example)

Answer (score 3):

Create a Form Service and Use *Mark FormGroup Touched* so that it will defaultly don't  display the Error Messages

```
import { FormService } from './services/form';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {
 public testForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInIt(){
 this.testForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
    this.FormService.markFormGroupTouched(this.testForm);
})
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Balaji, thanks for your support.... did you check this with my sample...but it is not working

Comment: can you please , apply your idea into that sample.?

Comment: @kumaresan_sd sure will apply this to your solution, please wait